# How to use In-App Purchase promo code use in my android application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am trying to use In-App Purchase promo code in my android application. Same as define in “In-app Promotions” in developer “billing_promotions” page. But it not works properly, when I am uninstalling my app, my promo code not work. The application again shows the purchase button and the promo code not work, it says the promo code already used. How to detect purchased the app using promo code. How I can solve it?

My In-App Purchase promo code step
In my activity's onResume() method use getPurchases(), within my onResume() method I use BroadcastReceiver and register my BroadcastReceiver as myPromoReceiver, using “IntentFilter - PURCHASES_UPDATED”

In my activity's onActivityResult()

And unRegisterReceiver(myPromoReceiver) in onPause() method.

Still it’s not work, how I can solve it? Please help me.

Comment: Hi @Rz do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here carefully:
https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

and also have a look at the sample code:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive

If you follow it carefully, it should work. The sample code already has the `PURCHASES_UPDATED` broadcastReceiver implemented, so you don't have to do it (it's implemented in `IabBroadcastReceiver.java`).

Good luck!